# Why aren't my motion detector lights working?

Tags: electrical, lighting, outdoor, motion-sensor

I have 4 motion sensing lights on 4 corners of my home and only one works and the other three do not light-up when I walk by... what might be the problem?

Here is an attached picture to show the model I'm using. Its for outdoor use.

I have also tried changing the bulbs but that does not help me either.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Many models seem to be sensitive to power surges. A lighting storm or frequent episodes of lights flickering have destroyed several of my sensors over the years. Some models have a switch on the detector head. The switch may allow you to test the unit by placing it in test mode. If that option is not available you will have to disassemble the fixture and use a noncontact voltage tester to verify power is present at the fixture.